# R.java file automatically deleted on clean up

Tags: android

When i cleaned up my project my R.java file got deleted automatically. My project has huge codes. I don't want to re-create my project and copy the codes into it. I know the R.java file was deleted due to some error in resources. I have huge data in resource(layouts, xml, strings.xml etc). How to tract down which file in resource has the error. Please help. Thank you

Comment: If you are using an IDE, then it will tell you where the error is

Comment: Are you using eclipse？

Comment: yes i am using eclipse. How to deal now?

Comment: Have you tried to save? Many times this action solves the problems

Comment: yes. I did save my files. Not working. How to get that R.java back

Answer (score 0):

When you rebuild the project again, R.java will get created.

Comment: How to rebuild the project? Where is the option?

Comment: In eclipse - Project > Clean , will clean your project . You could also see an "Auto Build" option, which is checked by default. When it is checked, you don't need to build your project, this happens automatically. If this behaviour is unwanted, uncheck this option and click build project whenever you want.

Comment: In Android Studio - Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: i am using eclipse. Help

Answer (score 0):

R.java isn't meant to be manually edited. It's automatically generated by the build process and can/will change even if the file is never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

R.java file will be automatically regenerated.But before that you have to check there will be an `error in manifest ,xml and your java codes`.If there is no error in that then `clean your project and rebuild.`